# In Julia 1.0, how to set a named tuple with only one key value pair?

Tags: julia

When I run

`t = (one = "one", two = 2)
typeof(t)`

in REPL, I get

`NamedTuple{(:one, :two),Tuple{String,Int64}}`

but when I run

`t = (one = "one")
typeof(t)`

I get `String` as type.

Is it possible to set a named tuple with just one named value so that I can access for example t[1] as well as t.one and get "one" returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a comma, i.e.

```
julia> t = (one = "one",)
(one = "one",)

julia> typeof(t)
NamedTuple{(:one,),Tuple{String}}
```

The reason why `t = (one = "one")` doesn't work is because it's equivalent to `t = one = "one"`. So you are defining two variables both with value "one".

```
julia> t = (one = "one")
"one"

julia> typeof(t)
String

julia> typeof(one)
String
```